# How to disable specular in cycles render?

Tags: roughness

I've created white box over blue large box in blender.

In rendered view with cycles, the bottom of white box is painted with blue color regardless roughness.

Why roughness parameter can't disable specular?
Is there anyway to disable it in cycles?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Cycles* tries to recreate realistic light distributions. If a blue surface is illuminated, blue light is bouncing off from it and hits other surfaces. So if you don't want realistic light bounces, you should probably use *Eevee* in general.

But anyway if you want to completely disable it in *Cycles* you can do the following:

First of all, you use the term yourself when you ask "Why **roughness** parameter can't disable **specular**? Because *Roughness* is how sharp the specular reflection is, completely rough does not mean not specular at all (which is almost impossible for real material surfaces), just very very blurred and broad. If you want to get rid of specularity completely, there is a *Specular* value in the *Principled BSDF* as well which you can set to 0.

[image: specular value]

However, even if you do that and the surface of the cube would not reflect anything, the bouncing blue light would still illuminate the diffuse part of the surface. So in order to disable that, you have to go to the *Object Properties* of the plane and under *Visibility* > *Ray Visibility* you have to disable *Diffuse*. And you could also disable *Glossy* here, in this case you would not need to disable specularity on the cube material. Just note that this way the plane will not effect any object's diffuse and glossy channels in the scene.

[image: ray visibility]

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and very detailed description! I've understood the reason and method to disable it. Just in case, Let me confirm to make sure that it can't disable part of multiple objects over the blue plane. right?

Comment: @Sheile Yes, that's right. This affects all objects above the plane. If you want to have different effects on different objects I guess you will have to do it with multiple render layers in the _Compositor_.

Answer (score 1):

Roughness only "*Specifies microfacet roughness of the surface for diffuse and specular reflection.*" ([source](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/principled.html)).
It will not remove reflections, think of it more like a blur.

Cycles is a path tracer, it literally bounces rays of light around your scene to get your render. If you don't want that, you can change Light Paths settings in the Render settings. There's a preset for only direct lighting:

[image]

If you want to make an object not send light back to other like it should, use [@Gordn Brinkmann's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/304012/53447) on your plane.